# Portia Scrappy fails to load responsive

Tags: javascript, python, html, web-crawler, screen-scraping

I installed [Portia](https://github.com/scrapinghub/portia) on my machine to crawl content with interactive supporting from it. I found its headless browser, Splash, can not load responsive images, i.e www.bbc.com

I knew Portia removes all javascript in HTML but this case it may need to render these images.

Is there any ways to attach javascript in order to

1. lookup placeholder elements
2. replace placeholders with transparent
   images
3. update src attribute for each image and assign the best
   quality/size ratio URL

like https://github.com/BBC-News/Imager.js ?

I found a function in Portia project but did not get its point, please give me some hints to try

```
def populate_window_object(self):
        main_frame = self.tab.web_page.mainFrame()
        main_frame.addToJavaScriptWindowObject('__portiaApi', self.js_api)
        self.tab.run_js_files(
            os.path.join(self.assets, 'splash_content_scripts'),
            handle_errors=False)
```